# How do I make div a clickable link?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

So, I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to make the 2 left divs (**volunteer sign-up** and **Request a volunteer**) on my home page be clickable links. I currently have them change color when you hover over them but how do I make them link to there appropriate page. Any help w

http://partners.sbceo.org

Comment: Simply wrap the `<div>` by an anchor tag; This is allowed in HTML5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the div in an anchor tag.

```
<a href="your-link-here">
   <div></div>
</a>
```

Comment: +1 for nice and simple and not faffing around with JS/Jquery etc

Comment: Im fairly new to all this, how would I apply this to my wordpress site? The theme is currently set up where the homepage has 2 panels for left box on homepage. How do I wrap it in a anchor tag? so lost, sorry I could probably do it via Dreamweaver but I don't even know how to access the html portion of the pages. http://s8.postimg.org/toy8ba3dx/Screen_Shot_2014_08_12_at_4_24_58_PM.png

Comment: My problem @CrudeLogic is I just don't know where to apply it. Since the editor of the page is made up of these boxes and no html is being generated (http://s8.postimg.org/toy8ba3dx/Screen_Shot_2014_08_12_at_4_24_58_PM.png) I can't get the html code that the boxes are making. I would normally just use the text editor on the wordpress page and all the html would be right there. My guess is that I need to change it via the home-page.php page.

Comment: @CrudeLogic http://s11.postimg.org/5jpamm5ar/Screen_Shot_2014_08_13_at_11_27_01_AM.png

Comment: @PaoRad can you please put your code in to a jsfiddle for me? it would make it much easier for me to show you.

Comment: @PaoRad do as you have on your jsfiddle. Do you have the wordpress page up and runing?

Comment: @CrudeLogic how do I implement this to my wordpress page. http://jsfiddle.net/nynvbjeu/1/

Comment: @CrudeLogic I do have the page up and running, http://partners.sbceo.org. But where do i implement the code I created? My problem is that the wordpress page doesn't generate the code being used.

Comment: @PaoRad i cannot visit your website

Comment: @CrudeLogic Try it without www. Also, thank you for the help, greatly appreciated

Comment: @PaoRad i cannot visit your website, with or without the www.

Comment: @PaoRad this comment string is getting too long, i would like to move it to the chat but you do not have that privilege yet

Comment: @CrudeLogic its says my reputation is too low. Anyway we can exchange emails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59306/discussion-between-crudelogic-and-pao-rad).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="mydiv" data-href="http://stackoverflow.com"></div>

<script>
  $('.mydiv').on('click', function(){
    window.location = $(this).data('href');
  })
</script>
```

this way you could use more than one clickable div

Answer (score -1):

Give the div a class or other identifier. Then using jQuery do something like:

```
$('identifier').click(function(){
   window.location = "your url";
});
```

None jQuery:

```
<div id="hello"></div>

function linkTo(url){
   window.location = url;
}
el = document.getElementById('hello');
el.onclick = linkTo('some website');
```

Answer (score -1):

i can't see the link but you can do this using Javascript:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='http://google.com/'">

</div>
```